# SignalR .Net Client could not find method in hub

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I'm following this guide: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client#callserver

I have the following:

```
_hubProxy = _hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("appHub");
_hubConnection.Start().Wait();
_hubProxy.Invoke("SendNavbarMessage", _hubConnection.ConnectionId).Wait();
```

Originally, I had a complex type being passed vie Invoke, but to debug I'm trying to use a parameterless hub method.  My hub:

```
[HubName("appHub")]
public class AppHub : Hub {
      // prep
    public void SendNavbarMessage() {
         // do stuff
    }
}
```

When I call `Invoke()`, I see the following error:

> {"'SendNavbarMessage' method could not be resolved."}

This is with Detailed error messages enabled in the signalR configuration... I get no other details.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoke sends one parameter to the method, but your Hub method has no parameters

```
_hubProxy.Invoke("SendNavbarMessage", _hubConnection.ConnectionId)
```

Should maybe be

```
_hubProxy.Invoke("SendNavbarMessage");
```

Comment: I owe you a beer man.  Really appreciate all the help.  I'm playing with this now and you're right, but does this mean that the documentation is incorrect?  They call the method with an extra parameter too, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Yes, I do believe the documentation is incorrect. I checked the actual code and there Invoke does not take the connection id. Also they misspell ConnectionID vs ConnectionId. Glad I can help!